# Ejercutar comando de windows como administrador desde PHP

Tags: php, windows, cmd

Tengo que ejecutar el siguiente comando como administrador desde PHP:

```
$salida="sintaxis\insertarlo.exe sintaxis\sumar.cpp";
$respuesta=array();
$estado;
exec($salida,$respuesta,$estado);
```

pero al parecer como es un .exe se necesita que el comando se ejecute como administrador, existe alguna opcion para que el exec o otro comando ejecute un comando como administrador

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yo encontré una forma para ejecutar el comando sudo descargando el sudo.exe de aqui https://goharsha.com/blog/sudo-command-prompt/ y agregarlo  la variable path de windows y se ejecutaria de esta manera:

```
$salida="sudo sintaxis\insertarlo.exe sintaxis\sumar.cpp";
$respuesta=array();
$estado;
exec($salida,$respuesta,$estado);
```

si alguien tiene una mejor respuesta que me la diga por favor